# how to access property of a class that is a part of an array?

Tags: xcode

im pretty new to xcode, so sorry if these are basics but im having the next issue: i have a class Data that contains string friendID and string friendName.
then i also have an array dataArray of these classes. now how do i access an ID or Name inside the array of classes?

this doesnt seem to work and i cant find any other solution:

```
[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"friendID"]
```

and if its relevant, i made dataArray like this and it works:

```
if(friendDataEmpty==YES)
{
    NSMutableArray *tmpFriendID = [data valueForKey:@"id"]; // parsed data
    NSMutableArray *tmpFriendName = [data valueForKey:@"name"]; // parsed data

    for(int i=0;i<[tmpFriendID count];i++)
    {
        Data *data = [[Data alloc]init];
        data.friendID = [tmpFriendID objectAtIndex:i];
        data.friendName = [tmpFriendName objectAtIndex:i];
        [dataArray addObject:data];
        [data release];
    }
}
```

and thats the header of data

```
@interface data : NSObject {
NSString *friendID;
NSString *friendName;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *friendID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *friendName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this.

```
data *dat = (data *)[dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
NSString *friendID = data.firnedID;

// to set the value
data.firnedID = someValue;
```

*Side Note:* You should consider following the proper naming convention while you name your classes, methods, vars and other things. The "*data*" class should have been named "*Data*".

Comment: yeah that works now, thanks @EmptyStack and yea i am following proper naming but i changed the code a little bit when i posted it here and i misstyped the header Data. :) 

btw isnt it kind of uneffective to access classes inside arrays like that? for example in c you can simply access it through array[index].varname.subclassVarname.subclassVarname.. am i dealing with this problem the wrong way in objective c? any suggestions  how else should i save that kind of data?

Comment: I don't know the technical reason why *valueForKey:* didn't work for you. But, I hope `[[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] friendID]` (without using the *valueForKey:*) should work.

Comment: thanks, it works for reading the data now, but doesnt work if i want to write it. :(

any more advices? :)

really appriciate your help, btw:)

Comment: never mind, solved, thanks for your help :))

    [[dataArray objectAtIndex:index] setValue:var forKey:@"classVar"];